# Golang testing with functions

Tags: function, unit-testing, go

I am using a third-party library that is a wrapper over some C functions.  Unfortunately, nearly all of the Go functions are free (they don't have a receiver, they are not methods); not the design approach I would have taken but it is what I have.

Using just Go's standard "testing" library:

Is there a solution that allows me to create tests where I can mock functions?

Or is the solution to wrap the library into structures and interfaces, then mock the interface to achieve my goal?

---

I have created a monte carlo simulation that also process the produced dataset.  One of my evaluation algorithms looks for specific models that it then passes the third-party function for its evaluation. I know my edge cases and know what the call counts should be, and this is what I want to test.

Perhaps a simple counter is all that is needed?

---

Other projects using this library, that I have found, do not have full coverage or no testing at all.

Comment: What are "free" functions?

Comment: Functions without Go receivers.  They are not tied with a structure.

Comment: So, you mean "functions", since anything with a receiver would be considered a method. Functions are used extensively in most idiomatic go, and there's nothing stopping those from being unit tested. What exactly do you want to mock? Go usually doesn't take the path of "mock everything" that some languages use, which often just ends up testing the mocks more than anything useful.

Comment: The typical way to test a function is to pass input, and compare the output against what you expect. Whether mocks are necessary depends on the inputs and outputs--not on whether it's a function or a method. If you can provide some examples of what you're trying to test, a better answer may be possible. Otherwise, the only option really is guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a reference to the actual function whenever you need to call it.

Then, when you need to mock the function you just point the reference to a mock implementation.

Let's say this is your external function:

```
// this is the wrapper for an external function
func externalFunction(i int) int {
   return i * 10  // do something with input
}
```

You never call this directly but instead declare a reference to it:

```
var processInt func(int) int = externalFunction
```

When you need to invoke the function you do it using the reference:

```
fmt.Println(processInt(5))
```

Then, went you want to mock the function you just assign a mock implementation to that reference:

```
processInt = mockFunction
```

This playground puts it together and might be more clear than the explanation:

https://play.golang.org/p/xBuriFHlm9

If you have a function that receives a `func(int) int`, you can send that function either the actual `externalFunction` or the `mockFunction` when you want it to use the mock implementation.